# Biztalk 2010 - Salesforce CRUD Operation through WSDL purely

Tags: wsdl, salesforce, integration, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am working on BizTalk 2010 and SalesForce integration where I am purely using SalesForce enterprise WSDL to perform all operations.

I am successfully able to login and query through WSDL, now my test is I want to do CRUD operation on any object (eg. Quote or Contact etc) using WSDL purely - no C# code.

I want to know what would be the best option to achieve this, I suppose I have to create/update/delete quote in Salesforce. There is an option available with sObject but not sure how to create request (XML or XSD) that we would pass to Salesforce.

Can anybody guide me around this?

Not able to attach screenshot of schema file where it is showing only operations name on right pane and on left pane it showing all details, I want to know if I have to call create operation for quote object what would be the xml that I would pass with data for quote creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this Sample SOAP messages in xml format from Salesforce.com.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Sample_SOAP_Messages.

Now I able to do all operations purely from wsdl, not C# code.

Thank you all for your help.
Zahir Shaikh

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you want invoke the SalesForce web service using BizTalk Server?

Comment: Yes, I have imported Salesforce Enterprise wsdl, I am able to call login and query methods but not sure how to perform other operation such as insert update and delete on any object (Contact,Account,Quote etc.). There is request/response for every operation but not sure how to get or create schema or xml that would create, update and delete object in SFDC.

Comment: So you have imported the Salesforce wsdl into your BizTalk Visual Studio solution using the schema generation tool? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226552.aspx

Comment: In order to get the schemas from the WSDL, you need to generate shemas. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226552.aspx Please also read the tutorial from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577881.aspx or do a search in a search engine with the keywords: biztalk consume web service. You will find some tutorials...

Comment: Thanks for response, but still I am not able to get through. When I consumed Enterprise wsdl through BizTalk it generated the schema file but only showing operation names. I have attached screenshot in original question/post. It is showing  everything on left side and only operation name on right side. I want know how would I pass request for creating objects like quote/account etc. Ever xml sample would work for me.